# Does the mass of a nucleus increase when it is excited to higher energy levels

Tags: nuclear-physics, atomic-physics

If we consider an atomic nucleus that is excited to a higher energy level. This maybe due to absorption of gamma for example or as a result of some other decay or interaction.

Would the mass of that nucleus then be higher than one in ground state?

If so would this also affect the reduced mass of the electrons in the election orbitals?

If so would this affect the energy levels of those orbitals themselves?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/69704/increase-in-cloths-mass http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/144587/does-a-cooling-mass-lose-mass-as-it-radiates? http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/69780/an-atomic-bomb-explodes-inside-of-an-unbreakable-container-which-is-on-a-scale? http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/187975/can-change-in-temperature-cause-a-change-in-mass-of-an-object? http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/70919/can-one-create-mass-from-energy? http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/188157/does-a-fixed-amount-of-gas-have-slighty-more-mas

Answer (score 2):

yes.  It does increase the mass and this can be measured by ion cyclotron resonance.
The mass change is very small and theoretically it would affect the electron orbits but more likely due to redistribution of charge in the nucleus rather than the mass increase.